# Extract substring from string after third last occurrence of underscore

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I have a string in Linux shell. This string contains underscores in it.

I want to extract a substring from the string.

I want to extract the substring after the third occurrence of an underscore, counted from the end of the string.

```
file_name='email_Tracking_export_history_2018_08_15'
string_name="${file_name#*_*_*_}"
file_name2='email_Tracking_export_2018_08_15'
string_name2="${file_name2#*_*_*_}"

echo "$string_name"
echo "$string_name2"
```

The result

```
history_2018_08_15
2018_08_15
```

As you see, `string_name="${file_name#*_*_*_}"` is not working properly.

Desired result:

```
2018_08_15
2018_08_15
```

How can I achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in a single step, but it's a bit convoluted. After setting the filename

```
file_name='email_Tracking_export_history_2018_08_15'
```

we get the substring that contains everything *except* what we want to have in the end:

```
$ echo "${file_name%_*_*_*}"
email_Tracking_export_history
```

This is almost what we want, just an underscore missing, so we add that:

```
$ echo "${file_name%_*_*_*}_"
email_Tracking_export_history_
```

Now we know what we have to remove from the beginning of the string and insert that into the `${word#pattern}` expansion:

```
$ echo "${file_name#"${file_name%_*_*_*}_"}"
2018_08_15
```

or we assign it to a variable for further use:

```
string_name=${file_name#"${file_name%_*_*_*}_"}
              └───┬───┘ │  └───┬───┘ └─┬──┘  │
             outer word │  inner word  └─────┼──inner pattern
                        └───outer pattern────┘
```

And analogous for the second string.

Answer (score 0):

Use a temporary variable:

```
file_name='email_Tracking_export_history_2018_08_15'
temp="${file_name%_*_*_*}"
string_name="${file_name/${temp}_}"
file_name2='email_Tracking_export_2018_08_15'
temp="${file_name2%_*_*_*}"
string_name2="${file_name2/${temp}_}"

echo "$string_name"
echo "$string_name2"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using regex in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Extract substring from string after 3rd occurrence in reverse
function extract() {
    if [[ "$1" =~ _([^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+$) ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
}

file_name='email_Tracking_export_history_2018_08_15'
string_name=$(extract $file_name)

file_name2='email_Tracking_export_2018_08_15'
string_name2=$(extract $file_name2)

echo "$string_name"
echo "$string_name2"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% echo $file_name | rev | cut -f1-3 -d'_' | rev
2018_08_15
% echo $file_name2 | rev | cut -f1-3 -d'_' | rev
2018_08_15
```

`rev` reverses the string, making it easy to count the 3 underscores occurrences. The part of string you want to extract is then reversed back.

Answer (score 0):

Using (most) sed and BRE:

```
sed 's/.*_\([^_]*\(_[^_]*\)\{2\}\)$/\1/' <<< "$file_name"
2018_08_15
```

Using GNU sed and ERE:

```
sed -r 's/.*_([^_]*(_[^_]*){2})$/\1/' <<< "$file_name"
2018_08_15
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `expr` already banned to deepest hell even for string matching?:

```
$ expr "$file_name" : '.*_\([^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*\)'
2018_08_15
$ expr "$file_name2" : '.*_\([^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*\)'
2018_08_15
```

From https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html :

```
expr "$string" : '.*\($substring\)'

    Extracts $substring at end of $string, where $substring is a regular expression.
```